# How to query a mongoDB object to find if it contain any emoji

Tags: mongodb, emoji

I have a collection that records comments from users. Something like the below:

```
{
    _id:1
    "statusReason" : {
                       "text" : {
                                   "value" :"Hello there "
                                }
                     }

}
```

I need to write a query that can identify any comments containing any emoji.

> MongoDB version: 3.4.24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MongoDB stores by default using UTF-8, you can simply search with regex of the unicode range of the emojis that you are interested of. You can check for the latest unicode range for emojis [here](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt)

```js
db.collection.find({
  "statusReason.text.value": {
    "$regex": "[\\x{2194}-\\x{1FAF8}]"
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TCRg5n1XEaz) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks ray! I used something like this and seems it has solved my problem.
db.collection.find({
  "statusReason.text.value": {
    "$regex": "[\\x{2194}-\\x{1FAF8}]"
  }
})

Comment: @ray I tried using your example, but it seem to return non-emoji results as well. e.g.: https://mongoplayground.net/p/k5Mk2neClKG

Comment: @Roman updated the answer to use a more narrow range for unicode search for emoji as the one used by Lokesh Kumar. The idea is the same in the sense that you need to search within the unicode range of the emoji you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using that example:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "message": ""
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "message": "excellent service"
  }
]
```

And that query:

```
db.collection.find({
  message: {
    $in: [
      ""
    ]
  }
})
```

I returned the message you requested:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": 1,
    "message": ""
  }
]
```

Here you can see the query in Mongo playground: [Link to Mongo Playground]
[1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kC-HFsyJLNH)

Useful documentation:

- [$in operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#-in)

Comment: In this way, you will need to enumerate all emojis in the `$in` clause, which is likely not a scalable way.